# How to set sqlconnecton to datadirectory like in ASP.Net. i'm using C# form

Tags: c#, ado.net

This is my current sql connection

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Kenneth\VisualStudioProjects\Emp - Trainee\Emp - Trainee\sample.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

If I change `AttachDbFilename=|Datadirectory|sample.mdf` it doesn't work because it only works on website ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

Set `DataDirectory` in your C# code

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", @"C:\Kenneth\VisualStudioProjects\Emp - Trainee\Emp - Trainee\");
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataDirectory unless set using:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", "c:\\MyDataDirectory");
```

would be pointing at the application folder. If debugging the application from Visual Studio, this would be the bin\Debug folder. Try putting your database in the same place where your compiled exe is.

Comment: what do i need to do? if i spread my program to other computers how will i set the database source??

Comment: The simplest would be to place the database file in the same directory as the binaries (the exe file). An alternative is that you set the DataDirectory programatically to either a hard coded path where the database must be deployed or better a relative path by doing `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\MyDatabaseDir");`.